# Dynamically calculate frequency value?

Tags: iphone, audio, frequency

In my app, I want to find/calculate the audio frequency as dynamically when i am recording an audio and no need to save, play and all. Now i am trying to do that with help of an aurioToch sample code. In that sample, inside FFTBufferManager class methods such as GrabAudioData and ComputeFFT,Here I am not able to find where they are calculating frequency value as dynamically depends on the audio sound and I spent more than 5 days.please help me.

Comment: Dude, there is not just one frequency value. Fast Fourier Transform gives you a value for every frequency (range) as in this image. http://www.owlnet.rice.edu/~elec301/Projects02/adaptiveFilters/images/fft-partial.png If you really want, you could pick out a dominant frequency, but there may not be one.

Comment: """Here I am not able to find where they are calculating frequency value as dynamically depends on the audio sound and I spent more than 5 days.please help me.""" - I do not understand. To calculate weights of frequencies you need a sample of some length. If you are talking about "rolling" calculations, try taking the last 30 sec window or so ...

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan, thanks for your reply, i want to calculate show the frequency continuously while recording an audio.

Comment: I suggest starting with basics. Install Python and SciPy and play with  fft a bit. Go here:
http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-c2d2c5fbd32e67ca3d984f73bff4ad7c8541483b

and then search for fft.

Comment: The reason why I recommend Python is that you can get a working prototype in 20 lines of code or less.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use FFT if your audio signal is clear and pure. Just count the peaks and valleys. Or just peaks. Take that number and divide by the number of samples in your buffer, and then multiply by the sample rate. That's your frequency value.